# vue2 - Programmatically create component and slots

Tags: vue.js, templates, vuejs2, slots

When creating vue (2.17.4) components programmatically, it does not take data from the domnode. If you use new Vue() it does. For components created using Vue.component or Vue.extend, the props and domnode content is simply ignored.

I made a simple example to explain the issue

```js
const Test = Vue.component('Test',{
  name: 'Test',
  props: ['prop'],
  template: `<div class="hello">
                SLOTCONTENT: <slot name="name">default from template</slot><br>
                PROPS: {{$props}}
             </div>`

});

new Vue({el:'#el1'})
new Test({el:'#el2'})
new Test({el:'#el3', propsData:{prop:'el3prop from propsdata'}})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.min.js"></script>

Component created with new Vue()
<Test id="el1" prop="el1prop">
  <template #name>el1 (from markup)</template>
</Test>
<br><br> Component created with new Test()
<Test id="el2" prop="el2prop">
  <template #name>el2 (from markup)</template>
</Test>
<br><br> Component created with new Test() propsData supplied
<Test id="el3" prop="el3prop">
  <template #name>el3 (from markup)</template>
</Test>
```

As you see, only for the first component props and content are taken from the domnode. I can add props using the propsData option, but can I supply the dom node content and how? The documentation has nothing about this.

Comment: Comps aren't supposed to be instantiated as `new Test`. You can get a template from dom through innerHTML, etc and use it the way you need in dynamically defined component

Comment: So, then how do I programmatically create a Component if not using new Test()?

Comment: By using `new Vue`. You can provide necessary options to it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the behavior, but I can notice, that [`propsData`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData) should be used together with `Vue.extend`

```
var Comp = Vue.extend({
  props: ['msg'],
  template: '<div>{{ msg }}</div>'
})

var vm = new Comp({
  propsData: {
    msg: 'hello'
  }
})
```

Your components are also not really dynamic. They are hardcoded in the template.

Then why not do it simpler? Like in the playground below.

You can also create dynamic components this way iterating over component props with `v-for`.

Like this

```
<Test v-for="component in components" />
```

```js
Vue.component('Test',{
  name: 'Test',
  props: ['prop'],
  template: `
<div class="hello">
  SLOTCONTENT: <slot name="name">default from template</slot><br>
  PROPS: {{$props}}
</div>`
});

new Vue({el:'#app'})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Component created with new Vue()
  <Test id="el1" prop="el1prop">
    <template #name>el1 (from markup)</template>
  </Test>
  <br>
  <Test id="el2" prop="el2prop">
    <template #name>el2 (from markup)</template>
  </Test>
  <br>
  <Test id="el3" prop="el3prop">
    <template #name>el3 (from markup)</template>
  </Test>
</div>
```